# Location service accuracy

Tags: android, geolocation

I would like to know when my provider supply a city level location which is very bad and then re-generate a location.
For that I will have to know from which number until which number the accuracy is city level, I'm speaking about the getAccuracy() method.
Is there any list of accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getAccuracy()` returns the estimated accuracy in meters. You can decide, for example, that if the accuracy is greater than 1km, that you can ignore the location.

Comment: It returns the circle radios in meters?

Comment: Yes, it returns the circle radius in meters